# Passing strings by reference and value in C++

Tags: c++, string, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I want to declare a string, initialize it by passing it by reference, and then pass it by value to the 'outputfile' function.

The code below works, but I don't know why.  In main I would expect to pass the string 'filename' like

```
startup(&filename)
```

But that gives an error, and the code below doesn't.  Why?  Also, is there a better way to do this without using a return value?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void startup(std::string&);
void outputfile(std::string);
int main()
{
    std::string filename;
    startup(filename);
    outputfile(filename);
}   
void startup(std::string& name)
{
    cin >> name;
}
void outputfile(std::string name)
{
    cout << name;
}
```

Comment: `&filename` creates a pointer. Pointers and references are incompatible.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a return value?

Comment: The code "works" because it does *exactly* what you described. in your opening sentence, and does so well. Regarding the error with `&filename`, it shouldn't compile because a reference is not a pointer. See [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in). regarding their differences and similarities.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your code works as expected.

`&filename` returns the memory address of (aka a pointer to) `filename`, but `startup(std::string& name)` wants a reference, not a pointer.

References in C++ are simply passed with the normal "pass-by-value" syntax:

`startup(filename)` takes `filename` by reference.

---

If you modified the `startup` function to take a pointer to an `std::string` instead:

`void startup(std::string* name)`

then you would pass it using the address-of operator:

`startup(&filename)`

---

As a side note, you should also make the `outputfile` function take its parameter by reference, because there's no need to copy the string. And since you're not modifying the parameter, you should take it as a `const` reference:

```
void outputfile(const std::string& name)
```

For more info, [here are the rules of thumb for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139254/3425536) regarding how to pass function parameters.

Comment: startup(& filename) would take filename by reference

Comment: @alboforlizo No, `&filename` gives a pointer to `filename`, so that would take filename by pointer, not reference.